# Unable to convert date into the desired format like (Wed, Oct 21, 2015 at 13:04 PM)

Tags: php, date, format

i am trying to convert current date into the following format:

Example:
**Wed, Oct 21, 2015 at 13:04 PM**

Just like gmail.

i have searched a lot on internet but nothing helped. I have also studied the following link, 
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

but still unable to sort out my problem.

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$time = strtotime(Date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$month=date("F",$time);
$year=date("Y",$time);
$day=date("d",$time);
$hour=date("H",$time);
$minute=date("i",$time);
$x=date("A",$time);
$final=substr(date("l"),0,3).", ".substr($month,0,3)." ".$day.", ".$year." at ".$hour.":".$minute." ".$x;
echo $final;
?>
```

you'll get the desired output.
:)

Comment: wow! yes it works perfectly, thanks so much:)

Comment: Even though the answer produces the results, the code is overly complicated and hard to maintain. See my solution and @GolezTrol 's.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the date and time formatters. The lesser known are D for abbreviated day of the week, M for abbreviated month, and j for day number without leading 0. For the time format you can use g, which is 12 hour time without leading zero and A for uppercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem indication. The various letters and their meaning are listed on the [documentation page of the `date()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

You'll either need to escape the characters of `at` by adding a backslash for each of them. Or you can choose to format in two steps:

```
 echo date( 'D, M j, Y') . ' at ' . date('g:i A');
```

For a specific timestamp:

```
$timestamp = time();
echo date( 'D, M j, Y', $timestamp) . ' at ' . date('g:i A', $timestamp);
```

Using escaping and poored into a function:

```
function gmail_date($timestamp = null) {
  // Allow passing no time, just like date() does.
  if ($timestamp === null) $timestamp = time();

  return date( 'D, M j, Y \a\t g:i A', $timestamp);
}

echo gmail_date(time());
```

Comment: very simple and clever :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [PHP Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function for formatting tips.

```
echo date('D, M j, Y \a\t g:i A', strtotime('+2 weeks 1 hour'));
```

Returns **Wed, Nov 4, 2015 at 5:14 PM** which looks pretty legit.

Comment: oh yes, it is the simplest way thankss